# Make divs inside table cells the same height without javascript

Tags: html, css, dynamic, html-table

I would like to make two divs contained in table cells in a shared row both have the height of the taller div. I would like to do this without JS. Here is a fiddle with a simplified example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lem53dn7/1/

Here is the code from the fiddle:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>small content</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>this is some longer content that will wrap.
                 I want the other div to be the same height as this one.</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table{
    width: 200px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you need the equal height, to set up the borders?

Comment: @sdcr exactly, I want the borders to mark out equally sized and proportioned boxes with different content from one another

Comment: Why don't you set up the borders on the TD instead of DIV?

Comment: take out the div css and add these lines of code: table td{
   
    border: 1px solid black
    
}

Answer (score 1):

Add the following properties to your `div` rule:

```
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
```

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lem53dn7/4/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately I want the divs to be the same width as well and `display: inlinle-block;` messes that up. Here is an updated fiddle demonstrating this problem http://jsfiddle.net/Lem53dn7/6/ . Suggestions?

Comment: My only suggestion is to use [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead of tables. :) If you're alright with [the browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), it's definitely the way to go for layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a height to the TD elements and then make the DIVs height 100%:

```
table{
    width: 200px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    height: 100%;
}

table td {
    height: 100%;
}

div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lem53dn7/7/

Comment: the problem with this is that I don't know the desired height of the cells. This doesn't work for dynamic content

Comment: Updated my answer. Seems to work fine in every browser (didn't check IE). @kat